# How to sort vector < pair <int, int> >?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

I would like to sort vector by its second element. 
The code is following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool compare(const pair<int,int>&i, const pair<int,int>&j){
    return i.second < j.second;
}

int main()
{
    vector<pair<int,int> >a(100);

    // values for test
    a[0].first=0; a[0].second=21;
    a[1].first=1; a[1].second=100;
    a[2].first=2; a[2].second=100;
    a[3].first=3; a[3].second=30;
    a[4].first=4; a[4].second=17;

    sort(a.begin(),a.end(),compare);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        cout << a[i].second << " " << a[i].first << endl;
}
```

The program returns

```
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
```

Where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the rest 95 elements are not assigned, they are by default `(0,0)`. So you need to sort the first 5 elements only.

```
sort(a.begin(),a.begin()+5,compare);
```

Comment: Might want to fold in a description of why.

Comment: Or initialize to size 5 instead of 100. Or leave the size out entirely and just `push_back` each pair as needed.

Comment: @Yakk Description added.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay Yup. Not meant as a criticism of the answer; just enumerating a couple more options for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

The sorting of a `vector<pair<int, int> >` works just the way you use it. However you have another problem. This code - `vector<pair<int,int> >a(100);` creates a vector of size `100` and fills it with pairs of `(0,0)`. Thus when you sort it the first 5 elements are `(0,0)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your vector is of size 100, but you only populated 5 elements. The rest will all be (0, 0), which your compare() correctly puts at the front.